# Twitter API: Search keywords/hastags from users timeline

Tags: twitter

I want to use one of the twitter REST api feeds to search a keyword or hastag from their timeline.

Currently using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/users_username.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=4&q=keywordhere"></script>
```

This gets the 4 recent tweets, I added the q= to try filter keywords but it doesn't look like it supports that parameter.

Anyone know of a api call that can search a timeline AND hashtag?

Comment: Did you found a way to do it? I'm also trying to filter it, but so far nothing. I did the search approach defining "from" sources and words, but it wasn't what I was expecting.

Comment: There isn't a Twitter API endpoint that does this. A workaround would be to retrieve the timeline and then write your won code to filter the results.